# Performance issues while importing CSV files into Elasticsearch through Logstash

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to import some gigabytes of CSV files (approximately 10+ million rows with 5 columns) but the throughput is very low (~1MB/s). I'm not quite sure yet what the issue may be, but maybe someone here has some leads.

What throughput could I expect on an 8GB, i7 (octocore), SSD box, using the default Security Onion stack (Evaluation mode)? Are there any known throughput issues with importing CSV files using the CSV filter? Likewise for using the Date filter (to extract timestamp values from the CSV)?

Comment: I think you might have better luck asking this question on http://discuss.elastic.co

Comment: Thank you! Will do.